# Regex find all word after a group and up to first digit

Tags: python, regex

i've this string

- FTBVHT HJMOW W0001 **BIANCO NATURALE** 06 / 29 GENNAIO - 31 3 1020.00
- F6M0DT HLM7L F0758 **ROSA 2** 06 / 29 GENNAIO - 31 3 3060.00
- FXX14T JFMAL N0000 **NERO** 06 / 29 GENNAIO - 31 4 1520.00

the word of my interest is just **BIANCO NATURALE** and i have to esclude FTBVHT HJMOW W0001 for example in the first string. Of course are all word , but in my case FTBVHT HJMOW W0001 not have sense instead BIANCO NATURALE in italian means NATURAL WHITE

with regex is possible to get just the follow text  for each string?

- BIANCO NATURALE
- ROSA 2
- NERO

the string that i  want to match are always preceded by 3 groups of letters and numbers separated by spaces, the words can contain numbers, for examppe ROSA 2  and the words that i want to match are always followed at the end by a space and then one or more numbers  06 / 29 GENNAIO ( rappresent the fomrat datetime )

Comment: What's the criteria for those texts?

Comment: Why is `FTBVHT` not a word? What are the rules? Maybe sth. like this: [`^(?:[A-Z0-9]+\s+){3}(\D+)\s+`](https://regex101.com/r/RPnPXv/1) ?

Comment: It seems that you're looking for the first group of letters that comes after a "word" of the form `LDD...D` (where L denotes a letter of the alphabet and each D denotes a numerical digit) and before a number. Is that correct?

Comment: I'would like to get the word  BIANCO NATURALE in the string : FTBVHT HJMOW W0001 BIANCO NATURALE 06 / 29 GENNAIO - 31 3 1020.00

Comment: What people are getting at is that Regex does not understand the concept of a "word" vs. a random string of letters, unless you're matching from a specific list of valid word(s). So, for instance, if we know the word(s) we want to match are always preceded by 3 groups of letters and numbers separated by spaces, the words never contain numbers, and the words you want to match are always followed by a space and then one or more numbers, we can start defining a pattern. However if that's not true, we'd have to come up with different logic. That's what people want clarification on.

Comment: Are you sure you want `ROSA`? Looks to me that you need `ROSA 2`

Comment: Yess! you are right!! I want ROSA 2

Comment: Nobody knows what a Date format is. It's like 257 county's each with own language dialect and concept of _`date`_ formats. So there is _no_ end delimiter. And this `always preceded by 3 groups of` of .. from where ? Anywhere ? Is this free form text, i.e. can be anywhere in the text. Basically you don't have the ingredients to cook up a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following pattern.

```
^(?:[A-Z\d]+ ){3}(.+?) (?:\d+ / )?\d+ [A-Z]+
```

Here is an example.

```py
strings = ['FTBVHT HJMOW W0001 BIANCO NATURALE 06 / 29 GENNAIO - 31 3 1020.00',
           'F6M0DT HLM7L F0758 ROSA 2 06 / 29 FEBBRAIO- 31 3 3060.00',
           'F6M0DT HLM7L F0758 ROSA 1 01 MARZO- 31 3 3060.00',
           'FXX14T JFMAL N0000 NERO 06 / 29 APRILEXX- 31 4 1520.00']
pattern = r'^(?:[A-Z\d]+ ){3}(.+?) (?:\d+ / )?\d+ [A-Z]+'
for string in strings:
    print(re.match(pattern, string).group(1))
```

Output

```
BIANCO NATURALE
ROSA 2
ROSA 1
NERO
```

There is a full list of regular expression pattern specifiers from the *Python* documentation.
*[Regular Expression HOWTO — Python 3.11.4 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)*.

Additionally, *Wikipedia* offers a great article, which outlines most of the specifiers.
*[Wikipedia – Regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)*.

Comment: Very Good, tanks  last thing  : you suppose that GENNAIO in the string not is a costant ,  but is a variable string only just letter, how can i get  same result? strings = ['FTBVHT HJMOW W0001 BIANCO NATURALE 06 / 29 GENNAIO - 31 3 1020.00',
           'F6M0DT HLM7L F0758 ROSA 2 06 / 29 FEBBRAIO- 31 3 3060.00',
           'F6M0DT HLM7L F0758 ROSA 1 01 MARZO- 31 3 3060.00',
           'FXX14T JFMAL N0000 NERO 06 / 29 APRILEXX- 31 4 1520.00']

Comment: @Herojos, the same pattern, except change the _"GENNAIO"_ text to `[A-Z]+`.  I've updated my answer.